# Почему imagemin удаляет содержимое svg файла?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Использую такой `task` для обработки изображений. По сути `imagemin` должен сжимать `svg` файлы, но в итоге получается, что он просто удаляет содержимое.

До обработки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После обработки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
gulp.task('build:img', function() {
  gulp.src(path.src.img)
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      svgoPlugins: [{
        removeViewBox: false
      }],
      use: [pngquant()],
      interlaced: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
})
```

На всякий случай прикрепляю содержимое `svg` файла:

```html
<svg style="display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <symbol id='movie-clapper' viewBox="0 0 277.446 277.446">
        <path d="M59.488,117.299c-0.504-4.237-2.007-8.171-4.273-11.556l202.992-67.776L247.552,6.051
  c-1.549-4.638-6.566-7.141-11.201-5.594L15.54,74.182c-4.635,1.547-7.143,6.563-5.594,11.201l5.225,15.647
  c-5.216,4.843-8.488,11.752-8.488,19.415c0,9.924,5.486,18.586,13.582,23.127v125.02c0,4.891,3.967,8.853,8.854,8.853h232.793
  c4.885,0,8.852-3.963,8.852-8.853V117.299H59.488z M188.869,26.724l26.875-8.973l-6.467,26.14l-26.875,8.973L188.869,26.724z
   M122.47,48.893l26.877-8.973l-6.467,26.139l-26.875,8.974L122.47,48.893z M33.181,133.946c-7.442,0-13.498-6.056-13.498-13.5
  c0-7.444,6.056-13.5,13.498-13.5c7.444,0,13.5,6.056,13.5,13.5C46.681,127.89,40.625,133.946,33.181,133.946z M56.074,71.062
  l26.877-8.973l-6.467,26.14l-26.877,8.974L56.074,71.062z M82.476,147.192H54.142l14.412-22.746h28.334L82.476,147.192z
   M138.554,124.446h28.334l-14.412,22.746h-28.334L138.554,124.446z M131.599,234.372v-60l47.783,30L131.599,234.372z
   M222.476,147.192h-28.334l14.412-22.746h28.334L222.476,147.192z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id='laptop' viewBox="0 0 92.821 92.821">
  <g>
   <g>
    <path d="M77.45,65.06V52.924h-4.452v9.702c0,1.517-1.242,2.756-2.756,2.756H15.106
     c-1.514,0-2.756-1.238-2.756-2.756V29.554c0-1.521,1.242-2.759,2.756-2.759H46.65v-2.827H11.066c-1.739,0-3.167,1.417-3.167,3.16
     v18.971V65.06v3.16L0,77.704c0,2.62,2.122,4.746,4.738,4.746h75.868c2.616,0,4.738-2.126,4.738-4.746l-7.899-9.484v-3.16H77.45z
      M49.002,80.864H36.354c-0.44,0-0.791-0.351-0.791-0.791s0.351-0.791,0.791-0.791h12.644c0.433,0,0.791,0.351,0.791,0.791
     C49.782,80.513,49.435,80.864,49.002,80.864z M29.644,77.704l2.412-2.895h21.237l2.412,2.895
     C55.705,77.704,29.644,77.704,29.644,77.704z"/>
    <g>
     <rect x="37.485" y="47.287" width="6.603" height="6.596"/>
     <rect x="41.622" y="38.219" width="6.599" height="6.603"/>
     <rect x="48.114" y="46.5" width="6.599" height="6.599"/>
     <rect x="53.361" y="35.534" width="7.831" height="7.831"/>
     <rect x="64.437" y="11.531" width="7.831" height="7.831"/>
     <rect x="50.229" y="25.693" width="7.831" height="7.831"/>
     <rect x="62.537" y="22.343" width="11.184" height="11.184"/>
     <rect x="70.89" y="35.824" width="13.528" height="13.532"/>
     <rect x="76.011" y="10.372" width="16.81" height="16.81"/>
     <rect x="60.518" y="44.263" width="7.831" height="7.831"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id='next' viewBox="0 0 240.823 240.823">
     <path id="Chevron_Right_1_" d="M183.189,111.816L74.892,3.555c-4.752-4.74-12.451-4.74-17.215,0c-4.752,4.74-4.752,12.439,0,17.179
  l99.707,99.671l-99.695,99.671c-4.752,4.74-4.752,12.439,0,17.191c4.752,4.74,12.463,4.74,17.215,0l108.297-108.261
  C187.881,124.315,187.881,116.495,183.189,111.816z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id='pencil' viewBox="0 0 485.219 485.22">
     <path d="M467.476,146.438l-21.445,21.455L317.35,39.23l21.445-21.457c23.689-23.692,62.104-23.692,85.795,0l42.886,42.897
  C491.133,84.349,491.133,122.748,467.476,146.438z M167.233,403.748c-5.922,5.922-5.922,15.513,0,21.436
  c5.925,5.955,15.521,5.955,21.443,0L424.59,189.335l-21.469-21.457L167.233,403.748z M60,296.54c-5.925,5.927-5.925,15.514,0,21.44
  c5.922,5.923,15.518,5.923,21.443,0L317.35,82.113L295.914,60.67L60,296.54z M338.767,103.54L102.881,339.421
  c-11.845,11.822-11.815,31.041,0,42.886c11.85,11.846,31.038,11.901,42.914-0.032l235.886-235.837L338.767,103.54z
   M145.734,446.572c-7.253-7.262-10.749-16.465-12.05-25.948c-3.083,0.476-6.188,0.919-9.36,0.919
  c-16.202,0-31.419-6.333-42.881-17.795c-11.462-11.491-17.77-26.687-17.77-42.887c0-2.954,0.443-5.833,0.859-8.703
  c-9.803-1.335-18.864-5.629-25.972-12.737c-0.682-0.677-0.917-1.596-1.538-2.338L0,485.216l147.748-36.986
  C147.097,447.637,146.36,447.193,145.734,446.572z"/>
    </symbol>
 
 <symbol id='star' viewBox="0 0 306 306">
  <polygon points="153,230.775 247.35,299.625 211.65,187.425 306,121.125 191.25,121.125 153,6.375 114.75,121.125 0,121.125 
   94.35,187.425 58.65,299.625"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='houses' viewBox="0 0 484.738 484.738">
  <path d="M131.012,438.372h85.624v-87.557h51.467v87.557h85.624V46.366H131.012V438.372z M257.993,92.564h51.466v51.467h-51.466
   V92.564z M257.993,175.279h51.466v51.467h-51.466V175.279z M257.993,257.992h51.466v51.467h-51.466V257.992z M175.279,92.564
   h51.466v51.467h-51.466V92.564z M175.279,175.279h51.466v51.467h-51.466V175.279z M175.279,257.992h51.466v51.467h-51.466V257.992
   z"/>
  <path d="M373.719,81.482V358.66h33.065v79.712h77.954V81.482H373.719z M444.437,321.009H397.58v-46.856h46.856V321.009z
    M444.437,245.703H397.58v-46.855h46.856V245.703z M444.437,170.398H397.58v-46.855h46.856V170.398z"/>
  <path d="M0,438.372h77.954V358.66h33.065V81.482H0V438.372z M40.302,123.543h46.856v46.855H40.302V123.543z M40.302,198.848
   h46.856v46.855H40.302V198.848z M40.302,274.151h46.856v46.855H40.302V274.151z"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='search' viewBox="0 0 410.23 410.23">
  <path d="M401.625,364.092l-107.1-107.1c19.125-26.775,30.6-59.288,30.6-93.713c0-89.888-72.675-162.562-162.562-162.562
  S0,73.392,0,163.279s72.675,162.562,162.562,162.562c34.425,0,66.938-11.475,93.713-30.6l107.1,107.1
  c9.562,9.562,26.775,9.562,38.25,0l0,0C413.1,390.867,413.1,375.566,401.625,364.092z M162.562,287.592
  c-68.85,0-124.312-55.463-124.312-124.312c0-68.85,55.462-124.312,124.312-124.312c68.85,0,124.312,55.462,124.312,124.312
  C286.875,232.129,231.412,287.592,162.562,287.592z"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='visible-field' viewBox="0 0 98.48 98.48">
  <path d="M97.204,45.788c-0.865-1.02-21.537-24.945-47.963-24.945c-26.427,0-47.098,23.925-47.965,24.946
  c-1.701,2-1.701,4.902,0.001,6.904c0.866,1.02,21.537,24.944,47.964,24.944c26.426,0,47.098-23.926,47.964-24.946
  C98.906,50.691,98.906,47.789,97.204,45.788z M57.313,35.215c1.777-0.97,4.255,0.143,5.534,2.485
  c1.279,2.343,0.875,5.029-0.902,5.999c-1.776,0.971-4.255-0.143-5.535-2.485C55.132,38.871,55.535,36.185,57.313,35.215z
   M49.241,68.969c-18.46,0-33.995-14.177-39.372-19.729c3.631-3.75,11.898-11.429,22.567-16.021
  c-2.081,3.166-3.301,6.949-3.301,11.021c0,11.104,9.001,20.105,20.105,20.105s20.106-9.001,20.106-20.105
  c0-4.072-1.219-7.855-3.3-11.021C76.715,37.812,84.981,45.49,88.612,49.24C83.235,54.795,67.7,68.969,49.241,68.969z"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='comment-black' viewBox="0 0 612 612">
  <path d="M83.455,464.734l78.364,91.104c10.015,11.656,26.539,11.545,36.637,0l79.727-91.104h305.917
  c15.411,0,27.901-12.49,27.901-28.013V75.502c0-15.495-12.212-28.041-27.874-28.041H27.874C12.49,47.461,0,59.952,0,75.502v361.219
  c0,15.467,12.323,28.013,27.791,28.013H83.455z M111.273,164.91c0-3.394,2.754-6.176,6.12-6.176h349.396
  c3.422,0,6.12,2.754,6.12,6.176v15.467c0,3.394-2.754,6.176-6.12,6.176H117.393c-3.421,0-6.12-2.754-6.12-6.176V164.91z
   M111.273,248.364c0-3.394,2.754-6.176,6.12-6.176h349.396c3.422,0,6.12,2.754,6.12,6.176v15.467c0,3.394-2.754,6.176-6.12,6.176
  H117.393c-3.421,0-6.12-2.754-6.12-6.176V248.364z M111.273,331.819c0-3.394,2.615-6.176,5.814-6.176h238.735
  c3.171,0,5.814,2.754,5.814,6.176v15.467c0,3.394-2.615,6.176-5.814,6.176H117.087c-3.171,0-5.814-2.754-5.814-6.176V331.819z"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='coin' viewBox="0 0 387.469 387.469">
  <path d="M104.515,47.127l10.508,4.585c-7.289,4.463-10.578,8.827-9.746,12.983c0.856,4.294,4.781,7.996,11.677,11.007
  c6.352,2.773,13.836,4.274,22.883,4.59c8.921,0.309,22.683-2.2,40.919-7.464c4.53-1.311,8.081-2.074,10.547-2.264
  c2.414-0.19,4.36,0.081,6.128,0.855c1.217,0.531,4.927,2.147-4.396,6.219c-6.056,2.643-12.327,3.731-18.635,3.235
  c-4.991-0.389-10.045,0.531-12.915,2.356l-5.603,3.563c-2.449,1.556-2.945,3.546-1.33,5.296c1.612,1.75,5.131,3.028,9.364,3.408
  c13.836,1.242,27.493-0.351,40.614-4.712l14.184,6.193c5.041,2.2,13.207,2.2,18.246,0.005c5.037-2.201,5.037-5.767,0-7.966
  l-14.678-6.408c6.447-4.096,9.838-8.236,10.076-12.331c0.284-4.791-3.586-8.973-11.499-12.428
  c-5.648-2.466-12.09-3.992-19.136-4.534c-7.047-0.547-13.727-0.242-19.842,0.905c-6.033,1.134-15.215,3.422-27.235,6.786
  c-5.231,1.449-8.779,2.188-10.557,2.199c-1.699,0.009-3.222-0.26-4.402-0.777c-4.188-1.824-0.669-4.131,3.02-5.741
  c4.58-1.999,9.467-2.943,14.522-2.81c5.068,0.134,9.848-1.049,12.199-3.011l3.25-2.711c2.056-1.714,1.946-3.77-0.287-5.444
  c-2.231-1.671-6.276-2.727-10.708-2.793c-9.619-0.138-18.896,1.148-28.23,3.913l-10.694-4.667c-5.04-2.2-13.207-2.2-18.246,0
  C99.479,41.362,99.479,44.928,104.515,47.127z"/>
  <path d="M326.447,104.012c0.854-3.551,1.291-7.168,1.291-10.834V81.59c0-23.154-17.287-44.325-48.677-59.612
  C249.96,7.805,211.49,0,170.738,0C129.986,0,91.517,7.805,62.415,21.978C31.025,37.265,13.738,58.436,13.738,81.59v11.588
  c0,22.833,16.82,43.733,47.387,58.968c-0.848,3.534-1.395,7.938-1.395,10.782v2.114c-29.688,15.173-45.992,35.786-45.992,58.27
  V234.9c0,15.613,7.871,30.321,22.616,42.936c-1.995,5.332-3.035,10.833-3.035,16.455v11.588c0,23.154,17.287,44.325,48.677,59.612
  c29.102,14.173,67.571,21.978,108.323,21.978c40.752,0,79.222-7.805,108.323-21.978c31.39-15.287,48.677-36.458,48.677-59.612
  v-11.588c0-15.61-7.864-30.316-22.603-42.929c1.993-5.333,3.021-10.839,3.021-16.462v-2.114
  c29.688-15.173,45.992-35.786,45.992-58.271v-11.588C373.73,140.121,356.948,119.243,326.447,104.012z M35.679,71.784
  c4.547-11.561,16.932-22.786,35.493-31.825C97.6,27.088,132.96,20,170.738,20c37.778,0,73.139,7.088,99.566,19.959
  c18.562,9.039,30.946,20.265,35.493,31.825c-16.064,27.942-71.876,48.316-135.06,48.316S51.742,99.727,35.679,71.784z
   M35.679,213.507c3.697-9.399,12.601-18.569,25.769-26.53c5.073,18.229,21.303,34.656,46.96,47.151
  c29.102,14.173,67.571,21.978,108.323,21.978c3.983,0,7.938-0.097,11.871-0.244c-17.791,3.826-37.438,5.962-57.863,5.962
  C107.555,261.823,51.742,241.449,35.679,213.507z M325.379,284.485c-16.064,27.942-71.876,48.316-135.06,48.316
  c-54.888,0-104.183-15.383-126.718-37.738c28.959,13.815,66.928,21.427,107.137,21.427c40.752,0,79.222-7.805,108.323-21.978
  c15.078-7.344,26.892-16.047,35.109-25.674C319.473,273.861,323.275,279.135,325.379,284.485z M216.73,201.439
  c-55.166,0-104.709-15.532-127.088-38.071c24.167,7.414,52.041,11.4,81.096,11.4c40.752,0,79.222-7.805,108.323-21.977
  c17.622-8.582,30.798-19.019,38.967-30.619c17.591,8.885,29.359,19.757,33.762,30.951
  C335.727,181.064,279.914,201.439,216.73,201.439z"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='email' viewBox="0 0 230.17 230.17">
  <path d="M230,49.585c0-0.263,0.181-0.519,0.169-0.779l-70.24,67.68l70.156,65.518c0.041-0.468-0.085-0.94-0.085-1.418V49.585z"/>
  <path d="M149.207,126.901l-28.674,27.588c-1.451,1.396-3.325,2.096-5.2,2.096c-1.836,0-3.672-0.67-5.113-2.013l-28.596-26.647
   L11.01,195.989c1.717,0.617,3.56,1.096,5.49,1.096h197.667c2.866,0,5.554-0.873,7.891-2.175L149.207,126.901z"/>
  <path d="M115.251,138.757L222.447,35.496c-2.427-1.443-5.252-2.411-8.28-2.411H16.5c-3.943,0-7.556,1.531-10.37,3.866
   L115.251,138.757z"/>
  <path d="M0,52.1v128.484c0,1.475,0.339,2.897,0.707,4.256l69.738-67.156L0,52.1z"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='location' viewBox="0 0 430.114 430.114">
  <path id="Facebook_Places" d="M356.208,107.051c-1.531-5.738-4.64-11.852-6.94-17.205C321.746,23.704,261.611,0,213.055,0
  C148.054,0,76.463,43.586,66.905,133.427v18.355c0,0.766,0.264,7.647,0.639,11.089c5.358,42.816,39.143,88.32,64.375,131.136
  c27.146,45.873,55.314,90.999,83.221,136.106c17.208-29.436,34.354-59.259,51.17-87.933c4.583-8.415,9.903-16.825,14.491-24.857
  c3.058-5.348,8.9-10.696,11.569-15.672c27.145-49.699,70.838-99.782,70.838-149.104v-20.262
  C363.209,126.938,356.581,108.204,356.208,107.051z M214.245,199.193c-19.107,0-40.021-9.554-50.344-35.939
  c-1.538-4.2-1.414-12.617-1.414-13.388v-11.852c0-33.636,28.56-48.932,53.406-48.932c30.588,0,54.245,24.472,54.245,55.06
  C270.138,174.729,244.833,199.193,214.245,199.193z"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='newspaper' viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <path d="M28,7V3H0v22c0,0,0,4,4,4h25c0,0,3-0.062,3-4V7H28z M4,27c-2,0-2-2-2-2V5h24v20
   c0,0.921,0.284,1.559,0.676,2H4z"/>
  <rect x="4" y="9"  width="20" height="2"/>
  <rect x="15" y="21"  width="7" height="2"/>
  <rect x="15" y="17" width="9" height="2"/>
  <rect x="15" y="13" width="9" height="2"/>
  <rect x="4" y="13" width="9" height="10"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='forbidden' viewBox="0 0 174.239 174.239">
  <path d="M146.537,1.047c-1.396-1.396-3.681-1.396-5.077,0L89.658,52.849c-1.396,1.396-3.681,1.396-5.077,0L32.78,1.047
  c-1.396-1.396-3.681-1.396-5.077,0L1.047,27.702c-1.396,1.396-1.396,3.681,0,5.077l51.802,51.802c1.396,1.396,1.396,3.681,0,5.077
  L1.047,141.46c-1.396,1.396-1.396,3.681,0,5.077l26.655,26.655c1.396,1.396,3.681,1.396,5.077,0l51.802-51.802
  c1.396-1.396,3.681-1.396,5.077,0l51.801,51.801c1.396,1.396,3.681,1.396,5.077,0l26.655-26.655c1.396-1.396,1.396-3.681,0-5.077
  l-51.801-51.801c-1.396-1.396-1.396-3.681,0-5.077l51.801-51.801c1.396-1.396,1.396-3.681,0-5.077L146.537,1.047z"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='home' viewBox="0 0 460.298 460.297">
  <path d="M230.149,120.939L65.986,256.274c0,0.191-0.048,0.472-0.144,0.855c-0.094,0.38-0.144,0.656-0.144,0.852v137.041
   c0,4.948,1.809,9.236,5.426,12.847c3.616,3.613,7.898,5.431,12.847,5.431h109.63V303.664h73.097v109.64h109.629
   c4.948,0,9.236-1.814,12.847-5.435c3.617-3.607,5.432-7.898,5.432-12.847V257.981c0-0.76-0.104-1.334-0.288-1.707L230.149,120.939
   z"/>
  <path d="M457.122,225.438L394.6,173.476V56.989c0-2.663-0.856-4.853-2.574-6.567c-1.704-1.712-3.894-2.568-6.563-2.568h-54.816
   c-2.666,0-4.855,0.856-6.57,2.568c-1.711,1.714-2.566,3.905-2.566,6.567v55.673l-69.662-58.245
   c-6.084-4.949-13.318-7.423-21.694-7.423c-8.375,0-15.608,2.474-21.698,7.423L3.172,225.438c-1.903,1.52-2.946,3.566-3.14,6.136
   c-0.193,2.568,0.472,4.811,1.997,6.713l17.701,21.128c1.525,1.712,3.521,2.759,5.996,3.142c2.285,0.192,4.57-0.476,6.855-1.998
   L230.149,95.817l197.57,164.741c1.526,1.328,3.521,1.991,5.996,1.991h0.858c2.471-0.376,4.463-1.43,5.996-3.138l17.703-21.125
   c1.522-1.906,2.189-4.145,1.991-6.716C460.068,229.007,459.021,226.961,457.122,225.438z"/>
 </symbol>

 <symbol id='arrow-left' viewBox="0 0 306 306">
  <polygon points="247.35,35.7 211.65,0 58.65,153 211.65,306 247.35,270.3 130.05,153"/>
 </symbol>


</svg>
```

Comment: Уничтожает любой svg или только этот?

Comment: @Dantessss, проблема решена.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было у `SVG` спрайта убрать `display: none;`